# df -h not showing all the partitions of my computer

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I am using a computer as a server using Amazon Web Services. Suddenly, the webserver stopped working and it seems the computer hard drive is full. When I type `df -h` it says the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb4        47G   47G     0 100% /
```

However, the computer has several hard drives and should have more memory and partitions that are seemingly not shown.

I use Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Here is the output of fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/md1: 4000.8 GB, 4000793493504 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 976756224 cylinders, total 7814049792 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md0: 1930.4 GB, 1930393673728 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 471287518 cylinders, total 3770300144 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 reached end-of-life (EOL) status earlier this year. It's well past time to upgrade it. Also, the version of `fdisk` in Ubuntu 12.04 is useless on GPT disks, which you have, and its output even says what to do: Use `parted` (or `gdisk`) instead. Offhand, it looks like your additional partitions have been unmounted. Depending on the server type, this could easily lead to the root (`/`) filesystem filling up. You'd need to post `/etc/fstab` and `parted` or `gdisk` output for a better diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

df only shows mounted partitions.  It does not work on the raw block devices. Mount the partitions (and add them to fstab to make mounts permanant) to fix the issue.